# rails link_to_add repeat div atmost 5 times

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'am adding images using nested form rails, with link_to_add and link_to_remove.After adding atmost 5 images link_to_add should be disable and on clicking link_to_remove it should be enable again.

Comment: show us some  code so that we can help you

Comment: attach some code snippet so that we can understand and debug.

Answer (score 0):

I can show you path only-

1- make a session variable in which should be available on your image adding page although session variable are available on your all controller and view layer only

ex - `session[:image_id] ||= []`

2- At the time when you are saving image in action you need to push the image id in this session variable beside that at the action when you are removing the image you need to pop up the image id from `session[:image_id]`

```
if session[:image_id].include? params[:id]
  session[:image_id].delete(params[:id])
else
   session[:image_id] << params[:id]
end
```

3- After doing 2nd step you can add condition on your view page for add or remove accordingly in respect of `session[:image_id].count`

ex -

```
if session[:image_id].count <= 5
  //show add image link or remove link_image button
end
```

you can also add condition in controller size
ex-

```
if session[:image_id].include? params[:id]
  session[:image_id].delete(params[:id])
else
  if session[:image_id].count < 8
     session[:image_id] << params[:id]
  else
     flash.now[:error] = "you have exceeded limit of adding image."
  end
end
```

@masteraryan you can modify it according to your requirement.